# searching a string substring using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

hello i'm trying to search a string for its substrings and return "yes" if found.

for exp : i have string `Deracu876`, substrings are `{D,d,e,E,r,R,A,a,c,C,u,U,8,7,6}` so here is the result :

- `deracu876` :yes
- `Deracu8762`:no
- `Dderacu876` : yes
- `sNdAp725`:no

here is the code i wrote using regex but not working

```
import re

def match(text,pattern):
    # regex 

    # searching pattern 
    if re.search(pattern,text,re.IGNORECASE): 
        return('Yes')
    else: 
        return('No') 

text=input()
pattern=""
for w in text :
    pattern=pattern+'|'+w
print(match("Deracu8762",pattern))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your third example, in particular, cannot be explained by the information you have provided. This is a characteristic of questions, like this one, that are stated in terms of examples. Examples are meant for illustration, but are not a substitute for a precise, unambiguous statement of the problem, generally in words. Please edit to clarify...

Comment: ...Here's my guess: String 1 contains only letters and digits. String 2 is said to be *derived* from String 1 if String 2 can be obtained from String 1 by replacing each letter, say "a", in String 1 with "a", "A", "aA" or "Aa". Given two strings, I wish to determine if the second can be derived from the first." You need to clarify your question even though you have selected an answer, as many SO members may read your question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is putting a `|` at the beginning of the pattern, e.g. if `text` is `abc`, the pattern is `|a|b|c`. This will match an empty string, which is a substring of every string.

You can simply wrap `[]` around the characters, e.g. `[deracu876]'`. This matches any of those characters.

You also need to make another pattern that rejects characters that aren't in `text`. You can do this by putting the characters in `[^]`, e.g. `[^deracu876]`.

```
def match(text, substring):
    if re.search('[' + substring + ']', text, re.IGNORECASE) and not re.search('[^' + substring '], text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

text = input()
print(match("Deracu8762",text))
```

Comment: thanks,but it still prints yes for every string entered

Comment: Why are you using `re.IGNORECASE`? You said that `sNdAp725` should not match, but `A` is a substring if you ignore case.

Comment: it should  be "no" because it contains {s,N,p} which they are not part of the main string